# Elasticsearch index size

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, size

I have a quick question in elastic search. I am having HTML file and i just wanted to store it in my index with other fields.

I have created two different index as below,

option1: have the field as binary and convert the html to base64 **(myindex1 is the index name, Html field is compresed and base64 value)**

```
HTML = (zlib.compress(Html.encode('utf-8'),9)).encode('base64')
```

using the above code i am compressing and encoding to base64 before loading into myindex1.

```
"Html": {
      "type": "binary",
      "index": "no",
      "include_in_all": false,
      doc_values : false,
      store : true,
},
```

Oprion 2 : have the html as it is in string field **(myindex2 is the index name, Html field is plain string as it is)**

```
   "Html": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "no",
          "include_in_all": false,
          doc_values : false,
          store : true,
    },
```

Experiment:
1) i have collected 10K data samples
2) compresed and converted the filed "Html" to base64 and loaded into ES index (myindex1)
3) loaded same 10k data samples as it is in myindex2.

Theoretically, The size of compressed data should be small. so my assumption was that myindex1 size should be smaller than myindex2.

But when i verifed it,

- myindex1 -->   228.3mb
- myindex2 -->   222.3mb

As we see above the size of the myindex2 (without compression) is smaller.

Why the myindex2 size is smaller than myindex1?

Answer (score 0):

[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is not a compression algorithm but an encoding algorithm.

The size of Base64-encoded data is approximately 1.37 times larger than the unencoded data, so what you're observing is perfectly normal.

The main goal of Base64 is to encode binary data into ASCII format. If you're looking for a compression algorithm you have a [few choices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression), such as ZIP, LZF, etc

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What i meant by compression is this : Html = (zlib.compress(Html.encode('utf-8'),9)).encode('base64'). I am actually compress the string using zlib in python then convert it into Base64

Comment: Updated my question. I am using Zlib to compress Html filed in option1.

Comment: The zlib part was quite an important bit of information ;-)

Comment: Val, Yes. My bad missed to include it :). I am going to give a try in potion1 , changing the binary to string and check the size.

Comment: You should print the size of a sample HTML at each step of the process: raw -> after utf8 encoding -> after zlib compression -> after base64 encoding. Then you can compare the raw size with the base64 encoded size, that'll give you some hints.

Comment: I am seeing significant improvement, If i change the datatype to string in option1 (instead of binary). Meaning compresed and base64 Html is stored as string in ES. In that scenario it took only 160 MB.

Comment: Good, so this did help?